# C# Multiline Textbox: Adding a string after a line if it contains X

Tags: c#, textbox, multiline

What I'm trying to do is loop the contents of a multiline textbox (looping line by line), if it contains a certain keyword (for example if the line contains the word: `click()`) then on the next line i would add the word `sleep(5)`

Looping the textbox is no problem:

```
foreach (string line in txtBoxAdd.Lines)
{
   if (line.Contains("click()"))
   {
      Helpers.ReturnMessage(line);
   }
}
```

The part i am having an issue with is how to add the word `sleep(5)` on the next line after it has found the keyword `click()` for example.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to add `sleep(5)` into an existing line or in a new one below the matched string? Also, is this WinForms, WPF, WebForms,...?

Comment: on a new line underneath the matched one would be ideal, i'm using winforms :)

Comment: It's a multiline textbox which i paste lines of text into :)

Comment: You can't modify something that is being iterated with a `foreach` loop, so you'll have to switch to another approach, like using an indexed for loop.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed What?...sure it does.

Comment: It compiles fine and is definately a Textbox :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
List<string> lines = new List<string>(textBox1.Lines);

for(int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++) 
{
   if (lines[i].Contains("click()")) 
   {
      lines.Insert(i + 1, "sleep(5)");
      i++;
   }                
}

textBox1.Lines = lines.ToArray();
```

Note that it doesn't check to see if there is already a "sleep(5)" on the next line, and that the changes aren't applied to the textbox until the whole thing has been processed.

Comment: Thank you idle_Mind that is working great and has given me something to work on.

Comment: Why is it `i += 2` after _one_ new line has been inserted? The `i++` of the `for` statement will also execute in that case, so is it intentional that you skip _two_ lines?

Comment: You're absolutely right, @JeppeStigNielsen, it should be `i++`.  Code has been edited above.

Answer (score 1):

Fluent version:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            txtBoxAdd.Lines = new[] { "Line 1", "Line 2", "Line 3 contains the buzzword", "Line 4", "Line 5 has the buzzword too", "Line 6" };
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            InsertLineAfterBuzzword(buzzword: "buzzword", lineToAdd: "line to add");
        }

        private void InsertLineAfterBuzzword(string buzzword, string lineToAdd)
        {
            txtBoxAdd.Lines = txtBoxAdd.Lines
                                       .SelectMany(i => i.Contains(buzzword) ? new[] { i, lineToAdd } : new[] { i })
                                       .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I also thought of `.SelectMany(i => i.Contains(buzzword) ? new[] { i, lineToAdd } : new[] { i })`.

Comment: I like it.  ...but if you had to modify it to check if the next line **already** had "sleep(5)", how would you do it?  (I upvoted, by the way).

Comment: @ Idle_Mind, oh, thanks) I'll think about it.
Manual looping is of better performance anyway. But I like linq. It looks much prettier if performance is not a critical thing.

Comment: @ Idle_Mind, that's possible too, but isn't the most optimal https://dotnetfiddle.net/SwwWja